# Where's the time travel in Mannequin 2: On the Move?

Tags: time-travel, mannequin-2

I've just watched an episode of American Dad and Stan was saying he hates all movies with a time travelling premise except for [Mannequin 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannequin_Two:_On_the_Move).

**I couldn't see any time travel in the synopsis. Is there any?**

Comment: It's American Dad, so it's entirely possible that's the entire joke.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that's entirely possible,  bit you'd need to have seen Mannequin 2 to know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two elements of time-travel within the film. In the first few minutes of the film, **a character (the Princess) is turned into a statue through the use of a magical necklace. 1000 years later, she is turned back into a real person**. Although this isn't "time-travel" per se (she went the long way around) the use of magical *artificial hibernation* to prevent her from aging could be considered a way of time travelling through time.

Shortly afterwards, we find that **the main protagonists from the medieval period (the Prince and the Duke) are reincarnated in the present day** as a shop boy and a local aristocrat. Again, not time-travel per se, but easily confused as such.

Comment: Why am I not surprised that you've risen to the occasion once again?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - As 80's films go, it's certainly not the worst. The ending is dire, but the actual movie is quite fun and upbeat.